# Show bounty info in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, ios-app

I know, I know, [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), right? Well now you have a post to assign that tag to!

- On question list, show the [image: +50] next to bounty questions
- On the question, show a [image: i] bar to see bounty details.
- On the awarded answer, show the [image: +50] as well

Comment: I am looking into this.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if I should split this out to two or three independent feature requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have currently decided not to implement any question attributes on the question listing – this decision applied for other things as well, like locked, and migrated.

However, I did implement the other parts of your feature request:

**If a question has a bounty, you will see the following information bar:**

[image: Question Bounty Screenshot]
Tapping on the info icon will reveal some more details.

**When a bounty is awarded, you will see the amount awarded on the answer:** 
[image]

Comment: By the way, feel free to create another status-request post for the question list part of bounty. @mhlester

Comment: Should it also be another feature request for showing the bounty text in that pop-up?

Comment: I just saw in the android twin of this request that the API doesn't expose the bounty text, so I guess that should be another feature request. I'll let someone else do that though!